# Преобразование Mat в byte[] и обратно

Tags: java, opencv

Необходимо получить класс Mat, провести с ним манипуляции и сохранить в byte[], с последующим восстановлением byte[] в Mat.
Написал простейший пример:

```
    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (InputStream inputStream = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/little-image.png")) {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                inputStream.read(bytes);
                //Первое получение Mat
                Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(bytes), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
                System.out.println(mat);
                if (mat.empty()) {
                    System.out.println("empty");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("TYPE: " + CvType.typeToString(mat.type())); //Не пусто
                }

                //Копируем
                byte[] testImg = new byte[mat.cols() * mat.rows() * mat.channels()];
                int count = mat.get(0, 0, testImg);
                System.out.println("count: " + count);
                System.out.println("testImg.length: " + testImg.length);
                //Получаем из скопированного
                Mat mat1 = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(testImg), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
                System.out.println(mat1);
                if (mat1.empty()) {
                    System.out.println("empty"); //!!!!!!!!!!!!ПУСТО!
                } else {
                    System.out.println("TYPE: " + CvType.typeToString(mat1.type()));
                }
                mat.release();
                mat1.release();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Восстановление Mat из byte[] возвращает пустой Mat.

Comment: @zRrr, спасибо, добавьте как ответ именно такая конструкция сделал то что нужно:    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
   Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", mat, matOfByte);
   byte[] bytes1 = matOfByte.toArray();

Answer (score 1):

Так у Вас `testImg` пустой. Вы лишь инициализируете массив байт заданной длины, но ничем его не заполняете. По-умолчанию весь массив при инициализации заполняется нулями.

Comment: А как же вот это? int count = mat.get(0, 0, testImg); Данные в массиве точно есть.

Comment: @ezhov_da, если Вы о том, что `count` получается больше нуля, так это верно, ибо Вы создали массив байт какой-то размерности и Java заботливо заполнила его нулями, так что да, данные есть и это нули.

Comment: Я вам говорю о том, что строка mat.get(0, 0, testImg) производит копирование данных из Mat в byte[] и после этого в byte[] лежит: [36, 28, -19, 36, 28, -19, 36, 28, -19, 36, 28, -19, 36, 28, -19, 36, 28, -19, 36, 28, -19, 36, ... и т.д., так что массив не пустой, но он гораздо больше чем входной.

Comment: @ezhov_da, ну тогда предлагаю лезть в исходники и смотреть где "собака по рылась"

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", mat, matOfByte);
byte[] bytes1 = matOfByte.toArray();
```